# Search not finding correct results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, search

I am learning how to create rails search bars. I have a model named movies. I would like to search movies by title and display the results. I am doing this in the "new" view, not "index." I am also using will_paginate on my results. Currently, my search presents no results, even if the movie IS present. If I don't do the search, I still see all of my movies... but obviously, I need the search feature to work too. Can someone help?

new movie view:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <h2 class="white">Home</h2>
    <hr />
    <h4 class="white">Add Movie</h4>
    <%= form_for @movie, class: 'form-horizontal' do |m| %>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title" class="white">Title: </label><br/>
            <%= m.text_field :title,  class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"> 
            <label for="title" class="white">Year: </label><br/>
            <%= m.text_field :year, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= m.submit %> 
        <div class="form-group">
    <% end %>
</div>  
</div>

<hr />

<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<h4 class="white">Database</h4>
<%= form_tag new_movie_path, :method=> 'get' do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
<br />
    <% if @movies.exists? %>
    <div class="bg_white">
        <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Title
            </th>
            <th>
                Status
            </th>
            <th>
                Year
            </th>
            <th>
                Delete
            </th>
            <th>
                Edit
            </th>
        </tr>
        <% @movies.each do |m| %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= link_to m.title, new_movie_rental_path(m) %>
            </td> 
            <td> 
                <%= m.status %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= m.year %>
            </td>   
            <td> 
                <%= link_to "Delete", movie_path(m), method: :delete %>
            </td>  
            <td>
                <%= link_to "Edit", edit_movie_path(m) %>
            </td>  
        </tr>
        <% end %>
        </table>
    </div>
    <%= will_paginate @movies, class: 'white' %>
    <% else %>
        <p class="white">No movies have been entered</p>
    <% end %> 
</div>  
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <hr />
    <%= link_to "Add Customer", new_customer_path, class: 'white' %>
</div>
</div>
<br /><br />
```

Movie model:

```
class Movie < ApplicationRecord
has_many :rentals, dependent: :destroy 


def status 
    if self.rentals.empty?
        return "In Stock"
    else
        self.rentals.order(borrowed_on: :desc).each do |x|
            if !x.returned_on.nil?
                return "In Stock"
            else 
                return "Rented"
            end
        end
    end
end

def self.search(search)
    if search
        @movies = Movie.where(["title","%#{[:search]}%"])
    else
        all
    end 
end 

end
```

Movies controller

```
 def new
    @movie = Movie.new
    @movies = Movie.search(params[:search]).order(title: :asc).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15) 
 end
```

Comment: Did you check the logs, if you are getting the desired search parameters?
Can you please post the rails server logs of this request.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not very helpful. What is this code supposed to do, and what is it currently doing?

Comment: It doesn't display results. There is no error, it just doesn't give me any results. The table is blank.

Comment: Here is what the server log says when I search for ET.

Started GET "/movies/new?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=ET&commit=Search" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-12-01 10:37:46 -0800
Processing by MoviesController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"ET", "commit"=>"Search"}
  Rendering movies/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Movie Exists (1.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "movies" WHERE (title) LIMIT ? OFFSET ?  [["LIMIT", 1], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  Rendered movies/new.html.erb within layouts/application (33.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 854ms (Views: 813.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the problem is on this this class method you have as search scope:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    @movies = Movie.where(["title","%#{[:search]}%"])
  else
    all
  end 
end
```

I guess you were attempting to interpolate search params into the query,  but in this case using #{} you are passing the symbol search instead of interpolating it. Thus your query ends up being `SELECT 1 AS one FROM "movies" WHERE (title)`. But More importantly, you are leaving yourself VERY vulnerable to SQL injection by interpolating directly into the query. What if a user enters into the search field something like `')DROP TABLE MOVIES ('`? I'd rewrite it like this:

```
def self.search(search = nil)
  if search
    Movie.where('title LIKE :search', search: "%#{search}%")
  else
    Movie.scoped
  end
end
```

Notice also how i'm returning Movie.scoped instead of all when search is empty; that returns a relation, .all returns an array of movie objects, which you don't want if you will call `order` and other chains on it.

Read on sql injection and param interpolation:
http://rails-sqli.org/#where
  http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.0.1/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where

Comment: So, the way you have it above will protect the database from SQL injection?

Comment: Well, I'm not an expert on injection so I can't say it's 100% not possible, but interpolating directly into query strings is the most common mistake. Read on those two links at the end to learn more on how properly build queries and also other injection examples.

Comment: You should also read a bit on scope methods, this method might fit better into scope instead of class method. Here: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/02/active-record-scopes-vs-class-methods/